# custom module of Joomla

Tags: joomla

I want to access the configuration.php file from a custom front-end module. I want to set "var $offline" to o or 1 from the module(through radio) and then refresh page. i also want the module to show when the site is off line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to access the configuration.php directly. Instead, use the functions joomla provides to change the website into maintenance (/offline) mode.

Maintenance will not allow you to specify displayed modules. You will need to change Joomla to include it or custom code in maintenance mode.